# prevent form submit from closing list item

Tags: jquery, forms, form-submit

I have a form wrapped in a list item with css display none.
To view the form the user clicks a button causing jquery to invoke a slideToggle. GOOD
Unfortunately, when the user clicks the form's submit button it reverses the list item back to display none. BAD. as the user cannot see any form submit errors.
I'm, trying to stop the submit button from also closing the form. The form is created using Gravityforms, a wordpress plugin, so I cannot change the forms submit code. (I dont think?)

This is the html

```
<ul class="contact">
   <li>class="gravity-form">
   <div>
      <form>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="gform_footer left_label">
        <input type="submit" id="gform_submit_button_1" class="button gform_button"
        value="Submit" tabindex="5">
        </div>           
      </form>
   </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas. I'm thinking jquery selectors to travel up the DOM to force list item to diplay: list-item?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent form submit button from closing slide toggled list element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869745/prevent-form-submit-button-from-closing-slide-toggled-list-element)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Examples#Example_5%3a_Event_Propagation) on event propagation.  Using `event.stopPropagation()` will stop the event from bubbling up the DOM without preventing the default action.

```
<input type="submit" id="gform_submit_button_1" class="button gform_button"
    value="Submit" tabindex="5" onclick="stopEvent(event);">
```

And inside your javascript:

```
function stopEvent(event)
{
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Now, when your button gets clicked, your parent elements won't receive the click event.

Comment: Hi I ave now added the onclick="stopEvent(event);" to my submit button code and created a jquery functionjQuery.fn.stopEvent = function(event) {
event.stopPropagation(); but the form is still closing? Thanks i advance
};

Comment: You don't need a jquery function.  The function should be written as above, outside the document.ready() call.  Besides, if you want to call a jQuery function it needs to be $.stopEvent(event).